# Node.js - NPM package zmq vs zeromq

Tags: node.js, npm, zeromq

I found these two bindings of ZMQ for Node.js. It seems, that both offer an equivalent API. Does anyone know pros and/or cons?

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/zmq
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/zeromq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/zeromq points to this github repo https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js which is maintained by the official zeromq project.

If the api is equivalent then choose the project that has the most incentive to keep up to date and support customers (such as yourself).

In this case, use the more official client.